# 'filterType' is not defined. trying to filter JSON objects trough react-mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

I have some code on `react` that should re-render the main page when I click. but it does not work. Can someone suggest an idea?

**/store/index.js**

```
import jsonObjects from './jsonObjects';

class RootStore {
    constructor() {
        this.jsonObjects = new jsonObjects(this);
    }
}

export default RootStore;
```

**/store/jsonObjects.js**

```
import sciences from '../data/sciences.json'

class JsonObjects {
    jsonObjectsList = observable(JSON.parse(sciences)) 

    get jsonObjects() {
        return this.jsonObjectsList.filter(jsonObjects => jsonObjects.deleted === false);
    }

    handleClick() {}
}

decorate(JsonObjects, {
    handleClick: action,
    jsonObjects: computed
})

export default JsonObjects;
```

Comment: ```
App.js 
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Discovers from “./Discovers”;
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
....

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Discovers />
  </div>
);

export default observer(App);
```

Comment: What is `action` in the _store/jsonObjects.js_ file?